# Making a blender built for 120V work on 220V

Tags: voltage, motor

I have a Vita Prep 3 (Vitamix) which is built for 120V and I want to use it in Europe with 220V.

[image: blueprint]

I'd like to avoid a converter because of its size.

There is a motor built for 220V available:

[image: motor]

Would I need to exchange any other parts than the plug and the motor?

Comment: Also any fuse(s).

Comment: maybe the switches,  is there a speed control circuit?

Comment: This seems to be a commercial blender, not a consumer appliance.

Answer (score 3):

The best part to exchange is the blender. Sell the 120v one. Buy a 240v one.

The 240v motor will probably cost 90% or more of a new blender anyway, once delivery, and the non-mass-market cost of supplying spares, have been taken into account. Then you have to fit it, with the risk of damaging motor or blender. And then you have a junk 120v motor cluttering the place.